# Entity framework : Including related entities on double related objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using entity frameworks.
I have this situation :

```
Obj1: ( ID (Primary key ) , name )
Obj2: ( ID ( Primary key ) , FromID ( foreign key obj1) , ToID (foreign key obj1) , quantity  )
```

So there are 2 relation between obj1 and obj2.
I want to select all obj2 and all related from obj1.
How should I include :

```
1. context.obj2.Include("FromID").Tolist   
or
2.context.obj2.include ("FromID").Include("ToID").Tolist
```

because the collection FromID and ToID may have all or some identical items.

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

So, in your Entity Framework POCOs, your model classes - as you describe them - would look something like this:

```
public class Obj1
{
    public int ID { get; set;}
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Obj2
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int FromID { get; set; }
    public int ToID { get; set; }
    public int quantity { get; set; }
}
```

The keys you describe would indicate the following additions, using [Data Annotations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583):

```
public class Obj1
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set;}
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Obj2
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int FromID { get; set; }
    public int ToID { get; set; }
    public int quantity { get; set; }
}
```

You don't mention any Navigation Properties explicitly in your model, but the fact that you wish to use `Include` implies that you want some ... I'm going to add some for each Foreign Key relationship you listed, with Navigation Properties on both sides of the relation - see [**InverseProperty and ForeignKey (attributes)**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583#Relationships):

```
public class Obj1
{
    public Obj1
    {
        Froms = new List<Obj2>();
        Tos = new List<Obj2>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set;}
    public string name { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("From")]
    public virtual ICollection<Obj2> Froms { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("To")]
    public virtual ICollection<Obj2> Tos { get; set; }
}

public class Obj2
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int quantity { get; set; }

    public int FromID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("FromID")]
    public virtual Obj1 From { get; set; }

    public int ToID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ToID")]
    public virtual Obj1 To { get; set; }
}
```

So, now that we have all the model classes set up, we can see that your relationship - being 1-to-many - would actually require the `Include` only when going the other way:

```
var obj1sWithAllFromsAndTos = context.Obj1s
                                     .Include(o => o.Froms)
                                     .Include(o => o.Tos)
                                     .ToList();
```

as opposed to

```
var obj2s = context.Obj2.ToList();
```

which would already include each related `Obj1` in its `From` and `To` properties.